# How do I get my child-theme to work with my theme's includes folder?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I am using the Canvas WordPress theme (by WooThemes.com) and successfully made a child-theme to override my CSS. However, I would also like to apply the same child-theme principles to my theme's "includes" folder which contains a variety of .php files. Any idea how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how Canvas calls in those files, you might not be able to do this.

If they're using [locate template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) or something similar ([get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part), for instance), you'll just need to create your own includes folder in the child theme and name the files the same as their couterparts in the parent theme.

If the parent theme uses require or require_once (or include/include_once), there's not going to be an easy way to override those parent theme files.

What are you trying to replace?

Comment: Also, assuming you paid for this theme, why not ask on the Woo Theme's support forum?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to modify the WooTabs widget. I was able to modify the CSS and other theme .php files via a child theme (these files sit in the parent theme's root directory level), but whenever I try to modify anything in the child theme that is below this directory level it doesn't seem to work..I tried creating an includes folder in the child theme and duplicating the respective folder structure but no go.

Comment: Parent -> Child inheritance doesn't apply to files below the root level of the theme, assuming the Woo theme operates on the same principles as regular WordPress themes.

Comment: @t31os - any workarounds you can think of or am I stuck just modifying the original file?

Comment: @Christopher Davis -- I do see this bit of code in index.php regarding get_template_part: <?php get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' ); ?>

Comment: @Brian - Not that i know of, i've never needed or wanted to do such a thing myself. I do however specifically remember reading about inheritance not working for files below the root level(which is why i commented).

Comment: You can make it work below the root level, but it's sort of hackish: just insert slashes into the file names.  So `get_template_part( 'content/loop', 'type' )` not pretty, but I've seen it in a few themes. The actual default inheritance doesn't work below the root level, though.

Comment: @Brain copy the woo themes tab widget code into your own widget class.  Then in your child theme's functions.php file, deregister the default widget and register your own with the same code (which you can edit, of course).  Resources: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/05/26/the-complete-guide-to-creating-widgets-in-wordpress-28 http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_widget http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget